# How to quote with TeX and output the reference?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm totally new to TeX but I've gone more or less through the http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/ Wiki but I didn't find anything beside `\quote` and `\quotation`.

How can I quote inline with the quote index? for example

> He said "Bla blah"$^{[14]}$

And how can I link this to a reference in the end?

Is there a tutorial or example for this?
Or any other quotation system like the harvard referencing system would be also OK.

Comment: Have a look at wiki chapter 5.3, [Bibliography Management](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management). The most recent and powerful solution is [biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the usual way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,super]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @article{shell2002use,
    title={{How to Use the IEEEtran \LaTeX{} Class}},
    author={Shell, Michael},
    journal={Journal of \LaTeX{} Class Files},
    volume={1},
    number={11},
    pages={10--20},
    year={2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  He said ``Bla blah''~\cite{shell2002use}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using the powerful `csquotes` package. If you want links to be hyper links, add `\usepackage{hyperref}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,super]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @article{shell2002use,
    title={{How to Use the IEEEtran \LaTeX{} Class}},
    author={Shell, Michael},
    journal={Journal of \LaTeX{} Class Files},
    volume={1},
    number={11},
    pages={10--20},
    year={2002}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  He said \enquote{Bla blah}~\cite{shell2002use}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compile the above codes with `pdflatex` →  `bibtex`  → `pdflatex` → `pdflatex` sequence.

`natbib` is used mainly to get the citation numbers in super script notation.

Comment: Thanks for the effort writing this sample. It also works but one problem: The program tells me that the citations are undefined and therefore in the pdf the index is just a '?' and there also are no references in the end. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: @Michael See the compile sequence above in the answer. Complete the sequence :-)

Comment: I've read it, but I didn't knew what to do with it but now I've got  it. Thanks :) It works perfect!

Comment: @Michael Glad you got it. :-)

Comment: Note, `csquotes` has a dedicated command for this situation: `textquote`. It can be customized to support different quotation styles etc. See [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf) for details, especially §9.2 gives detailed instructions with examples on how to use and customize `textquote`.